# I am trying to make a function which will return an id from array of object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to write a function which will return id from array of object but when i call that function it returns me what I pass.

```
export function getRecipeByID(requestId) {
  recipes.find(function (recipe) {
    return recipe.id === requestId;
  });
  return requestId;
  
}
```

for example I call function

```
getRecipeByID(1)
```

and it returns 1.

Comment: You literally put return requestId in the function, so why are you surprised it returns it?

Comment: Well, it does exactly what you ask for `return requestId;`

Comment: `which will return id from array of object`...well if you make it return the ID from the array, it will still return 1 because that was the ID which matched. Are you actually asking it to return the matched _object_ from the array?

Answer (score 3):

I guess what you want to write is this:

```
export function getRecipeByID(requestId) {
  return recipes.find(function (recipe) {
    return recipe.id === requestId;
  });
  
}
```

Notice that it doesn't return `requestId` but the result of `recipes.find()`

Comment: it returns undefined((

Comment: @ZulfiyaYumagulova it'll do that if `find` doesn't find any matching data. We don't know what's in your `recipes` array so we can't comment, but presumably there were no matches. Check the documentation where it mentions this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 1):

That's because you return `requestId` in your method while what you want is to return the result of `recipes.find`...

```
export function getRecipeByID(requestId) {
  return recipes.find(function (recipe) {
    return recipe.id === requestId;
  });  
}
```

Comment: it returns undefined ((

Answer (score 1):

you return requestId after using find which cause issue

```js
     const recipes = [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'pasta'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'sandwich'
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'pizza'
      }
    ]
     
    function getRecipeById(requestId) {
       const findRecipe = recipes.find(function (recipe) {
        return recipe.id === requestId;
      });
      return findRecipe;
    }
    console.log(getRecipeById(2)); // it will return{ id:2, name:"pasta" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export function getRecipeByID(requestId) {
  const recipe = recipes.find(item => item.id === requestId);
  if (recipe && recipe.id) {
    return recipe.id;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Explanation: You're not assigning the result of the find operation (the element that has been found or null if there was no matching element) to any variable and are simply returning the request id.

Also: I'd suggest you'd look into arrow functions. They have been available for some years now and make your code much easier to read. :)

Comment: Oh crap. I tried to answer in a way that was easy to understand and returned the id of the object if there was one present - which might match how I understood the question, but in itself is a bit silly... However, if you wanted to do that, a `return recipes.find(i => i.id === requestId) ? requestId : undefined` would be enough. If you want to return the whole object, just replacing lines 3-5 of my original answer by `return recipe` is enough to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a function that return the same Id that you fetch, then do it:

```
export function getRecipeByID(requestId) {
      return requestId;
      
    }
```

otherwise, if want to fetch an Object of your list of object then you can simply try:

```
const array1 = [{}]
export function getRecipeByID(requestId) {
          return array1.find(element => element.id == requestId);
          
        }
```

Comment: Nice, please don't forget to pick this answer as a accepted answer.